# Force UITabBarController More tab to be visible in landscape (iPhone6+)

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, landscape, iphone-6-plus

The iTunes Store app on an iPhone 6+ shows the *More* tab both in portrait and in landscape orientation. Is it possible somehow for 3rd party apps using an `UITabBarController` to force displaying the *More* tab in both orientations?

On other iPhones the *More* tab is shown in both orientations. On iPhone6+ our app shows the *More* tab only in portrait mode (we have 6 view controllers in the `UITabBarController`), and in landscape all 6 tabs are shown directly in the tab bar.